# Owl Carousel Nav arrows Styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, owl-carousel

I am using Owl Carousel plugin in one of our Shopify themes, but the nav arrows are positioned on the bottom left of the carousel. I have tried different stylings, but none of them work...

What I am trying to achieve is have the Nav Arrows on the outside of the carousel, positioned halfway the images. See example below:

[image: Carousel with halfway positioned arrows]

HTML CODE I have so far:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 product-image" id="product-image">
     <div class="product-image-inner">
      {% assign current_variant = product.selected_or_first_available_variant %}
      {% assign featured_image = current_variant.featured_image | default: product.featured_image %}
      <a href="{{ featured_image | product_img_url: 'original' }}" class="featured-image elevatezoom">
        <img id="show-img" class="zoom-image" src="{{ featured_image | product_img_url: '1024x1024' }}" data-zoom-image="{{ featured_image | product_img_url: 'original' }}" alt="{{ product.title | escape }}" />
      </a>

          <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">

          {% for image in product.images %}
          <ul id="gallery-image" class="gallery-image-thumb item ">

          <li >
            <a class="thumb-img{% if forloop.index == 1 %} active{% endif %}" data-image="{{ image | product_img_url: '1024x1024' }}" data-zoom-image="{{ image | product_img_url: 'original' }}">
              <img src="{{ image.src | img_url: '500x500' }}" alt="{{ product.title | escape }}" class="thumb-prod">
            </a>
          </li>

            </ul>
          {% endfor %}
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
.owl-carousel{
  position: relative;
}

.owl-prev, .owl-next {
    position:absolute;
 }

.owl-prev {
    left:0;
    top: 25px;
 }

 .owl-next {
    right:0;
    top:25px;
 }
```

The code above generates the following:

[image: This is what I get]

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of how html is rendered. With the following options you can change almost every class the way you want

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded">
<div class="owl-stage-outer">
    <div class="owl-stage">
        <div class="owl-item">...</div>
        <div class="owl-item">...</div>
        <div class="owl-item">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="owl-nav">
    <div class="owl-prev">prev</div>
    <div class="owl-next">next</div>
</div>
<div class="owl-dots">
    <div class="owl-dot active"><span></span></div>
    <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
    <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
</div>
```

So in your CSS you could give the CSS to owl-nav class.
you can use position absolute with top and left to get the desired position.

Comment: I tried that option, but it would not work at all. Tried doing positioning both classes: owl-prev and owl-next to absolute, give them a top of 50% and such, but it does not center it halfway the image...

Comment: The parent element need to have position relative, try giving position relative to  the class owl-carousel

Comment: See updated, it works but the arrows are not always centered halfway the carousel when I switch to an ipad or some mobile devices

Comment: Give the value for top as 40% or 45%, check what fits the best, instead of a fixed pixel

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Works good on mobile and desktop, but it becomes off on ipad and tablets

Comment: Can you share the website URL so that I could check it?

Comment: I would like to do that privately

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184710/discussion-between-satpal-tanan-and-john-wheeler).